# Add a "reset position" button for hats

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2014

No matter how hard I try, it will always be ever so slightly wrong:

[image]

Could there be a button to reset rotation and size, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you remove the hat it resets.

I know that's not specifically what you asked for, but it resolves your "No matter how hard I try" issue.